# Is Vertex Array Object a part of Context?

Tags: opengl

To use *Vertex Array Object* in OpenGL 3.0, we use following steps to create the name of *vertex array object* and then bind it to the Context.

- glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO) = generates the name of vertex array
- glBindVertexArrays(&VAO) = binds the name with vertex array.

Unlike, when we create and use a Vertex Buffer, we generate the name, bind it, allocate memory and then fill data in the buffer.

- glGenBuffers( 1, &VBO ) = generate the name for vertex buffer
- glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO ) = bind the name to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
- glBufferData(....) = Allocate memory and fill data

As we have not allocated the memory for *Vertex Array Object* in these lines, **does this mean that memory for *Vertex Array Object* is already allocated as a part of Context** and using glBindVertexArrays() we reference a pointer to the allocated memory for vertex array object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> glBufferData(....) = Allocate memory and fill data

You are indeed allocating memory for the buffer. But that is *different* from allocating memory for the buffer *object*.

Let's put this in C++ terms. A buffer object is like a `vector<char>`. Doing `glGenBuffers/glBindBuffer` is like allocating a `vector<char>` object (and let's do it on the heap):

```
auto buffer = new vector<char>;
```

`buffer` points to a real, live object. `sizeof(*buffer)` will return a number of bytes of memory, which how much memory the object pointed to by `buffer` requires. You can request `buffer->size()` and it will return a legitimate and well-defined value.

`glGetBufferParameteri64v(target, GL_BUFFER_SIZE)` would be the equivalent of calling `buffer->size()`. You can call this function after creating the object, before you call `glBufferData`.

In both cases, `buffer->size()` and `GL_BUFFER_SIZE`, the size returned will be 0. Because you haven't put anything into the object yet. In both cases, the object now exists, but it is *empty*.

`glBufferData` is like calling `buffer->resize`. You are now telling the object you allocated to *itself* allocate some storage of a certain size and (optionally) fill it with certain data.

A vertex array object is different only its purpose. The purpose of a buffer object is to contain storage. The purpose of a vertex array object is to define the association between storage (stored in buffers) and vertex arrays that feed rendering operations.

A VAO in our C++ analogy is more like a regular struct:

```
struct VAO
{
  int elementBuffer;
  VertexFormat vf[16];
  VertexBufferBinding vb[16];
};
```

This `VAO` struct doesn't need allocated storage beyond `sizeof(VAO)`. Just like many C++ objects don't need to allocate storage besides themselves. Therefore, it doesn't have the equivalent of `glBufferData`.

So to answer your question, the memory for *all* OpenGL objects is owned by the OpenGL context that created them. It's just that *some* OpenGL objects can have additional storage beyond that for their basic object. `vector<char>` has an internal array of bytes. And buffer objects have an internal array of bytes.

VAOs don't have internal arrays of storage beyond the object itself.

Comment: Nicol, thank you for the explanation!
Is it correct that Vertex Buffer lives in GPU memory (VRAM) and Vertex Array Object on Client side/ CPU memory (RAM)?
If that's the case how Vertex Array Object which lives on RAM can point to data to VRAM?

Comment: @user2259784: Where the actual data for any object is stored is an implementation detail. The allocated storage for a buffer object lives in GPU-accessible memory. Whether that means "VRAM" or not depends on the driver.